# LaTeX code for formatting sequential equation references differently from non-sequential references?

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing, conditionals

Consider a simple macro, `\Eqs{ref1}{ref2}`, accepting references `ref1` and `ref2` as arguments. In the current environment, the commands `\ref{ref1}` and `\ref{ref2}` expand to simple unformatted integers, e.g. `15` and `16`. Call these *x1* and *x2*.

I would like for `\Eqs` to do the following:

- if *x2* = *x1* + 1, expand to "(*x1*--*x2*)" with '--' being an en-dash
- in any other case, expand to "(*x1*,*x2*)"

So for example, if `\ref{ref1}`, `\ref{ref2}`, `\ref{ref3}` expand to 15, 16, and 25, respectively, then `\Eqs{ref1}{ref2}` would yield "(15–16)" and `\Eqs{ref1}{ref3}` would yield "(15,25)".

Any help would be appreciated.

(Incidentally, the proverbial holy grail would be a macro that accepts a comma-separated list of references and then groups together consecutive ranges, e.g. `\Eqs{ref1,ref2,ref3}` would return "(15–16,25)", but I realize this is a tall order unless already implemented as part of some package.)

Comment: You may want to look into `cleveref`'s `\cref` macro.

Comment: @moewe It looks like `cleveref` does exactly what's needed here. It also, apparently, takes care of another 6 classes of reference issues I've always longed to fix in my documents. If you promote your comment to an answer, I'd like to give you credit for answering the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is an elementary implementation of what you're after. [`cleveref`](//ctan.org/pkg/cleveref), however, does far more in terms of the presentation and interaction with other packages. Additionally, it accepts a comma-separated list and does sorting of the elements.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{refcount}

\newcommand{\Eqs}[2]{%
  \mbox{\upshape
    (%
      \ref{#1}% Set first reference
      \ifnum\getrefnumber{#2}=\numexpr\getrefnumber{#1}+1\relax
        --% References are one apart
      \else
        ,\,% References are not one apart
      \fi
      \ref{#2}% Set second reference
    )%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{14}\refstepcounter{equation}\label{eq:15}% Equation 15
\refstepcounter{equation}\label{eq:16}% Equation 16
\setcounter{equation}{24}\refstepcounter{equation}\label{eq:25}% Equation 25

See \Eqs{eq:15}{eq:16}, or \Eqs{eq:15}{eq:25}.

\end{document}
```